# Molar mass of a mixture of two solids

Tags: organic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I wonder, if I wanted to know the molar mass of a some white crystalline solid that is a mix of $\ce{C6H12O6}$ and $\ce{C12H22O11}$, would I just do this :

$$170.1559 \; \ce{g/mol} + 343.2965 \;\ce{g/mol} = 522.4524 \; \ce{g} / 2 \ce{mol}$$

Thus : $261,2262 \; \ce{g/mol}$.

Would this be a correct operation ? Or it wouldn't make any physical sense ? Thank you!

Comment: Does the crystalline contain fifty percent of each?

Comment: Glucose + sucrose? The idea of an averaged molecular mass seems pointless to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a chemical mixture of sucrose and glucose.  In which case, you only talk about the molar mass of the two sugars separately.  The mass or number of moles of the mixture can be determined by knowing the ratio of sucrose and glucose in the mixture.  FYI... the molar mass of glucose is 180 g/mol (not 170).